# Is it possible to preload cache/image in incognito mode on selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, incognito-mode

I am doing a bot for get data a website. i use python and selenium open a chrome to fill form. I don't want the website block my ip or account, so i use different of proxy and run on incognito mode to protect myself such as ip, account information. I config browser by a function:

```
    def configBrowser(self, myProxy):    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=' + myProxy)
    chromePath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/chromedriver.exe"
    return webdriver.Chrome(chromePath, options=chrome_options)
```

However, my proxy is very slow, but the website have many image. So, it need >30 sec loading per page! To improve performance, is it possible some preload image / script from local when opening chrome in incognito mode?

Comment: I believe you can set an option to not load images.  You don't need incognito as the driver will use a fresh profile each time.  To use already cached images you'd want to use a specific profile.   I think incognito will erase the cache each time you close the browser.  Incognito will not protect you from a website at all... it's only for local side.

Comment: I have tried to not load image., but website need to pass CAPTCHA that I input manually . So image is need to load. I also use thread to start 2 or 3 browser at same time. As you said, let try non incognito  mode to run program are the same on web server?